# Save result to csv or an excel file during each iteration or simulation

Tags: r, export-to-csv

I am trying to save result from simulation as an excel or csv file. I would like to export the result after each iteration to one of these files. Is there an easy way to do it? Following is the toy example that I tried:

```
for(i in  1 : 10){
  if(i==1){write.csv(i,"test.csv")}
  if(i > 2){write.csv(i,"test.csv",append=TRUE)}
}
```

In this case, only the last value of 10 is saved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Ian pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60856708/680068) we can't change some argument for *write.csv*, so we need to use *write.table*, here is a simpler version of loop avoiding *if* statements:

```
for(i in  1:10){
  write.table(i, "test.csv", sep = ",",
              row.names = FALSE, col.names = i== 1, append = i > 1)
  }
```

Outputs below **test.scv**

```
"x"
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

Comment: @ zx8754 Thanks a lot. Exactly what I was looking for. This is useful when you are running large simulations and you get an error when you are far in your simulation and still like to see the results up to that point.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that `write.table` accepts `append = TRUE` and `write.csv` does not.

`help(write.table)`

> ...   arguments to write.table: **append**, col.names, sep, dec and
>   qmethod cannot be altered.

```
for(i in 1:3){
df <- data.frame(a = sample(1:10,10), b = sample(1:10,10), c = sample(1:10,10))
write.table(df, file = "test.csv",append = TRUE,sep=",",quote=TRUE,col.names = FALSE)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

How about saving your results in a data frame first and then exporting to csv? Like:

```
df <- data.frame(result = NA)
for (i in 1:10) {
  df[i, "result"] <- i
}
write.csv(df, file = "test.csv")
```